# Unable to use traefik for HTTP domain routing

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik

I created a simple REACT weather application and deployed it in docker swarm. Next I want to use traefik proxy to route the domain to "weather.localhost.com" but can't figure out how to.

I tried to test with basic services such as whoami (whoami.localhost.com) and nginx (nginx.localhost.com) and they are working fine. However when applying identical traefik labels to weather-app, it refused to work. I can still access the weather-app through localhost:3000 so the problem has to come from the communications between traefik and the app.

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  weather:
    image: 127.0.0.1:5000/weather
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-public"
      - "traefik.http.routers.weather.rule=Host(`weather.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.weather.entrypoints=web"
    networks:
      - traefik-public
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    entrypoint: ["npm", "start"]

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.5"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - traefik-ssl-certs:/ssl-certs
      - /etc/traefik:/etc/traefik
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - traefik-public

  whoami:
    image: "traefik/whoami"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-public"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web"
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    networks:
      - traefik-public
  
  nginx:
    image: "nginx:latest"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-public"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.rule=Host(`nginx.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.entrypoints=web"
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    networks:
      - traefik-public

networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true

volumes:
  traefik-ssl-certs:
    driver: local
```

Comment: Your React app runs in a browser on the host, so the host needs to send traffic to weather.localhost.com to 127.0.0.1. Usually that's accomplished by adding the name and address to the hosts file on the host. Depending on your host OS, that file is found in different places.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try:

1. Switch from `blah.localhost` to `blah.lvh.me` - Sadly setting up *.localhost requires you install dnsmasq or similar and tweak quite a lot of settings. There are a bunch of domains that various 3rd parties have registered that return 127.0.0.1 in response to wildcard queries.
2. To cater for potentially many domains, switch to HostRegexp - e.g. this rule allows for `traefik.*` so you can test with `traefik.localhost`, `traefik.lvh.me` or `traefik.example.com` as your mood takes you.

```
        traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule: HostRegexp("traefik.{any:.*}")
```